# where to get an overview over messages from IOT devices in Azure?

Tags: list, dashboard, alarm, azure-iot-hub

I will have some thousands of NB-IOT devices connected to Azure IOT-HUB, they will send different alarm messages in case something is wrong where they are, like high temperature etc. Are there some dashboard or list overview I can connect the IOT-HUB to ? I would like to have a list with all alarming IOT devices, i.e. if no alarm message/ceased alarm, then they shall not be in the list. (I can see the messages in the visual studio so the MQTT messages set-up is done).

BR

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to an "out of the box" feature for this would be to use IoT Hub queries. You can use device twins to set the device status. The status could be "nominal/alarm", that way you can use the [IoT Hub Query language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language) to extract a list of devices currently in a certain state.
You would need to update your devices to have the device report updates to the device twin, or you need to write a piece of code that takes the messages and updates the twin from the backend.

You mentioned a dashboard, I'm not aware of any out of the box solution for this, but you could use PowerBI to create a dashboard based on a number of data sources. There are many Azure components you can store your telemetry in, and you can use PowerBI to create a list of devices whose last message was an alarm. Putting Stream Analytics in between would enable you to store just the alarms in a database.

In short: there are many ways of getting to the same result, as far as I know, none will be out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Matthijs for your answer

Comment: If you think the answer is correct, could you mark it as such? Otherwise please let me know if I missed anything!